# DeleteMode.HardDelete not working as expected

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I currently have a process that is designed to iterate through an Inbox, parse the emails contained within, dump those to a JSON file, and delete the emails. They cannot go to the DeletedItems folder, and must be removed from the server immediately (so DeleteMode.HardDelete is the only option here).

There is an admin monitoring the Inbox to make sure the process is truly deleting the emails, and had alerted me this morning that the RecoverableItems folder is getting filled up. I had consulted [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/deleting-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange) to see if I had done something wrong. Additionally, I had made sure to look over [Delete Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.deletemode?view=exchange-ews-api) with the EWS API.

Now, the pertinent piece of code I have is the following:

```
Boolean moreItems = true;
        int loopNumber = 0;
        while (moreItems)
        {
            string filepath = "Outputs/";
            string filename = "some_filename.json";
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filepath + filename))
            {
                int itemsParsed = 0;
                while (moreItems && itemsParsed < 50000)
                // I want to split up the files into 50k item files. 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        FindItemsResults<Item> itemSet = i.GetItemSet();
                        foreach (Item x in itemSet.Items)
                        {
                            //Console.WriteLine($"Getting mailitem {x.Id}");
                            try 
                            {
                                x.Load(itemSetProperties);
                                EmailMessage email = em.BindEmail(service , x.Id);
                                metadata.Id = x.Id.ToString();
                                metadata.Subject = x.Subject.ToString();
                                metadata.Sender = email.From.Address.ToString();
                                metadata.Body = x.Body.ToString();
                                metadata.DateTimeReceived = x.DateTimeReceived;
                                metadata.DateTimeSent = x.DateTimeSent;
                                metadata.HasAttachments = email.HasAttachments;
                                serializer.Serialize(sw , metadata);
                                moreItems = itemSet.MoreAvailable;
                                itemsParsed += 1;
                                x.Delete(DeleteMode.HardDelete);
                            }
                            catch (ServiceRequestException sre)
                            { 
                                Console.WriteLine("\nTimeout caught.\n");
                                //Connection keeps getting reset every once in a while
                            }
                            catch (XmlException xle) 
                            {
                                x.Delete(DeleteMode.HardDelete);
                                // There are emails with incomplete xml in the body. These can be deleted
                            }
                            catch(Exception ex)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"Caught new exception: \n{ex.Message}");
                                Environment.Exit(0);
                                // I want to catch new exceptions and figure out why they're happening
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine($"Parsed {itemsParsed} items");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (ServiceRequestException exterior_sre)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Caught exterior exception");
                        // Still haven't figured this out yet, but it occurs once 
                        // in a rare while, and continuing does not affect the overall process
                    }
                }
            }
            loopNumber += 1;
            Console.WriteLine($"Moving to loop number {loopNumber}");
        }
```

The issue is that the items being deleted are *still* being sent to the RecoverableItems folder in the dumpster. In the interrim, I had asked that the admin see about altering the retention policy on RecoverableItems such that it would get cleared out sooner than the default.
My main question is why this is happening? The emails appear to be getting a SoftDelete, so I know that the delete call to EWS is occurring successfully, but the HardDelete seems to be getting ignored.

I am still relatively inexperienced with the EWS API and C# as a whole, so apologies in advance for any ignorance on my part.

**Update**
I have confirmed with the Admin that items are not landing in the "Purges" folder, where they should be landing. I also have checked with [this piece of documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/recoverable-items-folder/recoverable-items-folder), that outlines the need for setting up retention policies on the Recoverable Items folder.

I'll keep adding edits for this as I go.

Comment: @RyanWilson I forgot about that piece of documentation; I had sent an email to the admin earlier asking about this. I think there is some confusion on their end with respect to setting up retention policies, so I am working with them to see if the retention policy on the dumpster is too long. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @RyanWilson I have confirmed with the Admin that the deleted items are in fact not landing in the Purges folder, and are landing in RecoverableItems instead (despite the documentation).

Comment: @RyanWilson I think we have it figured out, and the solution stems from your comment, so if you want to post that as a solution, I will happily accept it.

Comment: Glad you got it working, I added as an answer as you requested.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is doing as it is designed with Hard Delete -

> ### Hard delete
>
> The item or folder is permanently deleted.
>
> Hard-deleted
>   items are placed in the Purges folder of the dumpster. This is like
>   when the recycling truck empties your curbside recycle container. The
>   items cannot be accessed from an email client like Outlook or Outlook
>   Web App, and, unless there is a hold set on the mailbox, the items
>   will be permanently deleted after a set period of time.
>
> You can read
>   more about item retention in the article Configure Deleted Item
>   Retention and Recoverable Items Quotas.
>
> NOTE: Folders are not placed in the Purges folder when they are hard
>   deleted. Hard-deleted folders are removed from the mailbox.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/deleting-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange